# Redshift RDS (PostgreSQL): Filter only 1 of 4 Columns

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, filtering, amazon-rds

What's the simplest way to write my query to return the following:

- signup_month
- total_signups
- business_signups
- total_users

Assume the **signups** table looks like this:

```
| date       | signup_email | tier         | users |
| ---------- | ------------ | ------------ | ----- |
| 2014-05-02 | personal     | trial        | 1     |
| 2014-05-04 | personal     | subscription | 1     |
| 2014-05-12 | personal     | subscription | 2     |
| 2014-05-25 | business     | trial        | 1     |
| 2014-06-02 | personal     | subscription | 1     |
| 2014-06-20 | business     | subscription | 10    |
| 2014-06-30 | business     | trial        | 5     |
```

Here's a basic query that just outputs 3 columns (signup_month, total_signups and total_users). I'm having trouble adding a 4th column for business_signups (exclude when signup_email = personal and tier = trial

```
SELECT
       DATE_PART(month,signup_date) AS signup_month,
       COUNT(signup_email) AS total_signups,
       SUM(users) AS total_users
       FROM signups
       GROUP BY 1;
```

However, I'm having a hard time counting the # of 'business_signups' without having to write 2 queries. I'm looking for output that looks like this:

```
| signup_month | total_signups | business_signups | total_users |
| ------------ | ------------- | ---------------- |------------ | 
| 5 (May)      | 4             | 1                | 5           |
| 6 (Jun)      | 3             | 2                | 16          |
```

What's the easiest way to add the last column that just filters for business_signups?

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag.  You are under the mistaken impression that RedShift is synonymous with Postgres.  It was forked long ago from a long obsolete branch of Postgres and the two are quite noticeably different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting conditional expression into `SUM`:

```
SELECT
    DATE_PART(month,signup_date) AS signup_month,
    COUNT(signup_email) AS total_signups,
    SUM(users) AS total_users,
    SUM(DECODE(signup_email, 'business', 1, 0)) as business_signups
FROM signups
GROUP BY 1;
```

or

```
SELECT
    DATE_PART(month,signup_date) AS signup_month,
    COUNT(signup_email) AS total_signups,
    SUM(users) AS total_users,
    SUM(CASE WHEN signup_email = 'personal' AND tier = 'trial' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) as business_signups
FROM signups
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: DECODE is exactly what I needed and works with the table I'm using. Thank you so much, Sergey!

Answer (score 3):

I would *strongly* recommend keeping the year with the month, unless you specifically want to combine the same month from different years (which your question does not suggest as the intention).

Then, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', signup_date) AS signup_month,
       COUNT(*) as total_signups,
       SUM(users) AS total_users,
       SUM( (signup_email = 'business')::int ) as business_signups
FROM signups
GROUP BY signup_month;
```

This assumes that business signups are really when the signup email is "business".  This is consistent with the data in the question.

Comment: Good call on including year and month @Gordon Linoff since my data does go back to Nov 2020